# Laravel modify Auth::user() query?

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel

I want to add some joins onto my Auth::user() query. How do I do this without creating a brand new query? I just want to be able to make the default call of Auth::user() different than:

```
    SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?
```

to

```
    SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN user_icons ON user_icons.ID = users.iconid WHERE `id` = ?
```

I'm using the default model User class.

Comment: What for? If you describe your relations properly, obtaining icon will be easy.

Comment: This should be handled via a relationship on the User model.

Comment: I want to reduce the number of queries I calling. When using relationships, it creates extra queries that I could otherwise join onto the Auth::user() query.

Comment: This doesn't create a join though, it runs two separate queries. I'm trying to avoid as many query calls as possible

Comment: You won't save anything. Laravel is smart enough to cache relations queries for you.

Comment: You are, in general, better off doing things the Laravel way. Your server won't blink at an extra query, and the reduced complexity of your code is well worth it.

Comment: Hi, I currently have setup using relationships. I just wanted to see if it was possible at all to do. Making sure queries are as optimised as possible is very important to my client's site since they have 100s of users online at a time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does provide a tip what to do, which is enough in my opinion. You shouldn't satisfy the needs if the needs themselves are wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel provides a way for you to extend the `Auth` functionality.  First, you need to create a class that implements the `Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface`. Once you have your class, you call `Auth::extend()` to configure `Auth` with your new class.

For your case, the easiest thing for you to do would be to create a class that extends `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider`. You'll want to update the `retrieveBy*` methods to add in your custom joins.  For example:

```
class MyEloquentUserProvider extends Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider {
    public function retrieveById($identifier) {
        return $this->createModel()->newQuery()->join(/*join params here*/)->find($identifier);
    }
    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token) {
        // your code with join added here
    }
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
        // your code with join added here
    }
}
```

Once your class is fleshed out, you need to tell Auth to use it:

```
Auth::extend('eloquent', function($app) {
    return new MyEloquentUserProvider($app['hash'], $app['config']['auth.model']);
});
```

The first parameter to the `Auth::extend` method is the name of the auth driver being used as defined in `app/config/auth.php`. If you want, you can create a new driver (e.g. 'myeloquent'), but you'd need to update your `Auth::extend` statement and your `app/config/auth.php` driver.

Once all this is done, `Auth::user()` will end up calling your `MyEloquentUserProvider::retrieveById` method.

Fair warning: I have not actually done this myself, and none of this is personally tested. You will probably want to check out the documentation ([L4.1 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.1/extending#authentication), [L4.2 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/extending#authentication)) and look at the Laravel code.

Other notes:

- People have already chimed in that this is probably not what you want to do. However, the this information may be helpful to you and others looking to extend Auth for some other reason.
- Considering your inner join, if a user does not have an associated user_icons record, `Auth::user()` will not return a record anymore, and the user probably won't be able to log in at all.

Comment: @RiKo Generally inside the `boot()` method of a service provider.

Comment: @patricus thank you for replying. I created question about laravel. Please check, i think you can help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616869/set-custom-sql-for-authorization-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1:n relation:

Add a "icons" table to you database with a foreign key "user_id".

Add a "Icon" Model to your models.

```
<?php

class Icon extends Eloquent{

  ...

}
?>
```

In Model Class "User" add a function:

```
public function icons() {
    return $this->hasMany('Icon');
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
$userIcons = Auth::user()->icons();
```

Comment: Remember that `Auth::user()->icons()` won't return any icons, but the query.

Comment: This doesn't create a join though, it runs two separate queries. I'm trying to avoid as many query calls as possible.