# set custom sql for Authorization in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am new on Laravel and use Authorization. I am looking for the way to change default sql for Auth. Actually, Laravel does it using this simple sql command at below:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login="something" AND password = "something" LIMIT 1
```

I am trying to change default sql like this:

```
SELECT
u.id, u.name, c.company
FROM
users u, companies c
WHERE 
u.login="something" AND 
u.password = "something" AND
u.companyId = c.id
LIMIT 1
```

I understood that I should create custom Authorization system: crate new user Provider and Auth Provider.

Firstly, I created Auth folder inside App and added there `CustomUserProvider.php`

**CustomUserProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as UserProviderInterface;
use App\Models\User;

class CustomUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {

    protected $model;

    public function __construct(UserContract $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {

    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {

    }

    public function updateRememberToken(UserContract $user, $token)
    {

    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {

    }

    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {

    }

}
```

My **customAuthProvider.php** file, in `App/Providers`:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Auth\CustomUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CustomAuthProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app['auth']->extend('custom',function()
        {
            return new CustomUserProvider(new User);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

At the end I set driver to custom in `config/Auth.php`

```
'driver' => 'custom'
```

I am looking for the way using this custom classes how can I use custom sql command for Authorization (Login)?
Or maybe this way is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this package and it helped me:

https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth/

Answer (score 1):

If all you need are additional constraints on the query that fetches user from the database during authentication, there is much simpler way to do that.

First of all, Laravel offers an `AuthenticatesUsers` trait that you can use in your controller to handle authentication requests. The default implementation fetches user from the database using `username` field and then, if matching user is found, it validates their password.

The list of attributes that is used to fetch user from the database can be customized by overriding `getCredentials` method in your controller. In your case the following should be enough to load user using their username and company id:

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password', 'companyId);
}
```

Once you add that, user should provide their username, companyId and password in the login form and they will be authenticated only if there exists a user with given username that belongs to given company and the password provided is valid.

**UPDATE:** If you decide not to use the trait, but want to authenticate users manually, you can do so in a really similar manner. When calling `Auth::attempt()` you just need to pass all the criteria that should be used to authenticate the user, e.g.:

```
Auth::attempt([
  'username' => Input::get('username'), 
  'companyId' => Input::get('companyId'), 
  'password' => Input::get('password')
]);
```

Comment: There is something misunderstanding. Where should I put this code exactly? to which controller?  `loginUsername()` gives an error, says that this method does not exist. How it will recognize `companyId`?

Comment: You should add AuthenticatesUsers trait to the controller that you want to handle your login requests, e.g. the AuthController that should come bundled with fresh Laravel project. This method is part of this trait.

Comment: I've updated the answer - it now contains example how to authenticate user using additional criteria without using the trait or AuthController

Comment: Auth::atempt is lucid. But I dont need companyId without relation with another table `companies`. Of course, without relation it is so simple to do it using Auth::attempt

Comment: You did not provide how to cross two tables (`users`, `companies`) while autentification?

Comment: Well, you use companyId to select user, so no need to use 2 tables. If you have defined user->company relation correctly in your model, then once authenticated you can access current user's company with Auth::user()->company

Comment: I should fetch company name from another table using companyId. the structur of table users:(`id`, `companyId`, `login`, `password`). The structur of table companies('`d`, `companyName`, `expiredDate`).While auth I should check if company's agreement  expired or not. If not, I should fetch user's information and company's name. If expired, laravel  must not give me the permission to access to the dashboard, should display an error message like this: Your agreement is expired. That is why I should use 2 tables on auth. Thank you so much for trying help me. I appreciated.

Comment: But I have a question: Laravel always use `SElECT * while auth`. I have too many columns and big user data. is there any way using for example: `SELECT id, name, companyName` ?

Comment: In my opinion you're trying to do too much in the authentication layer - it's purpose should be to check if user's credentials are valid and load the user. The rest - checking expiration, permission - should be done separately, in Middleware or in your controllers.

Comment: Then I will do it separately :) Thank you for your advice.